# Some tricks to simplify the following expression that has max between variables.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to simplify the following where $\alpha,\beta>0$

$$f(\alpha,\beta)=\max\{\alpha,\beta,1\}+\max\{\alpha,\beta\}- [1-\max\{\beta,\alpha\}]^+  =0 $$

where $[x]^+=\max(0,x)$. I know also that I can use the property

$$\max\{a,b\} = \frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{|b-a|}{2} \tag1$$

I was hoping to find a trick by exploiting the structure of the function  $f(\alpha,\beta)$ before using (1)...

Any ideas

Comment: Your formula for max(a,b) should have a plus sign between, not a minus (which would give the min(a,b)). Also if desired the (x)+ could be written as (x+|x|)/2.

Comment: I understand your first comment,and I have changed accordingly the question, however I don't understand your second comment? @coffeemath There is no reason why I choose b-a or a-b..

Comment: so you are wondering why I chose to write as |b-a| instaead |a-b|?

Comment: Tyrone: actually that part doesn't matter anyway, as far as simplifying the expression. It might not simplify much, if I find anything good I'll mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an intuitive sense, you can see that first first term is at least 1, the second term is some positive value, and the third term subtracts at most $1$ from the equation. Even if the first and last terms reach equality, the middle term will force the equation to be greater than 0, so there are no solutions.

And to show it mathematically:

Let $m = \max\{\alpha,\beta\}$

**Case 1**: $m \geq 1$

$$f(\alpha,\beta) = m + m = 0 \rightarrow 2m = 0 \rightarrow m = 0$$

So there are no solutions for $m \geq 1$

**Case 2**: $m < 1$

This suggests $\alpha, \beta < 1$, so the first $\max$ and the $[\ ]^+$ operator simplify:

$$f(\alpha,\beta) = 1 + m - (1-m)$$
$$f(\alpha,\beta) = 2m$$

Return to our initial conditions:
$$\alpha,\beta > 0 \Rightarrow m > 0$$
$$m > 0 \Rightarrow f(\alpha,\beta) > 0$$

But we are attempting to characterize solutions to $f(\alpha,\beta) = 0$, so there are no solutions for $0 < m < 1$.

Cases $1$ and $2$ imply that your equation has no solutions over the given domain. For constants other than $0$, you can apply similar reasoning to determine the answer. You will see that $f(\alpha,\beta) = c$ for $\alpha, \beta > 0$ does have solutions for $c > 0$.

Comment: A look at the six orderings of $\alpha,\beta,1$ shows the left side of the OP equation simplifies to $2 \max(\alpha,\beta)$ in all cases, making the solution of $f(\alpha,\beta)=c$ direct, provided one doesn't restrict to positive $\alpha,\beta$ and also [as stated in the above answer] there is a simple solution in case $c>0$ when we do restrict $\alpha,\beta>0.$ {And +1 on this answer.]

Comment: I did get $f(\alpha,\beta)=2m$ in both cases - I just found that it was more obvious how the $[\ ]^+$ operator was removed when the cases were split up.

In the case where $\alpha,\beta < 0$, you actually only get the solution $f(\alpha,\beta)=0$ regardless of the values. If just one of them is positive, then it still becomes $f(\alpha,\beta) = 2m$.